# Is it possible to keep archive functionality when setting up GMail as Exchange account on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, gmail, exchange-activesync

When you set up GMail on an iPhone normally, the delete icon in the mail app is replaced by an archive icon, as this is the most common action in GMail.

I changed my settings to configure GMail as an Exchange account, as I wanted to enable push email for this account.  But this has changed the archive icon to a delete icon.

Is it possible to maintain the archive icon while it's set up as a Gmail account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm actually about to ask the opposite question, but the delete functionality in Exchange GMail archives the email and does not delete it.

Comment: This isn't an answer, and should probably be a comment on the question instead.

Comment: I disagree. My answer to the question is that 'deleting' in exchange mode does not delete, it archives - which is what the OP wants.

Comment: Apologies, now that I re-read your answer I see what you mean.  I tested this and it works for me.  Thanks!